# Assigning property of NSManagedObject causes UISwitch to revert

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-data, uiswitch

I've encountered a very odd bug. The view in question is a `UITableView`, where each cell contains a `UISwitch` as its `accessoryView`. I have it wired up so that a change in value triggers `- (IBAction)toggleEnabled:(UISwitch *)theSwitch`, which looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleEnabled:(UISwitch *)theSwitch
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    Alarm *alarm = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    alarm.unrelatedProperty = @"This property is unrelated to the switch.";
}
```

The buggy behavior is that the switch immediately reverts back to its original state. As soon as you flick it, it flicks right back. I did a little more testing, changing my code to this:

```
- (IBAction)toggleEnabled:(UISwitch *)theSwitch
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    Alarm *alarm = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    alarm.unrelatedProperty = @"This property is unrelated to the switch.";
}
```

Now, the reverting behavior only occurs on the very first switch in the list (at row 0). All the other switches work fine, which leads me to believe that it's something to do with modifying an object at a given `indexPath`. The switches work fine with this code, so I'm pretty sure it's due to the assignment:

```
- (IBAction)toggleEnabled:(UISwitch *)theSwitch
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    Alarm *alarm = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Anyone know what could be happening? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a fetched results controller? What sets the state of the switch on the cell? I guess you're causing the cell to be reloaded and that resets the switch state...

Comment: Genius! My `configureCell` method was being called each time the data updated, which was instantiating a new switch. Fixed!